# TEIID30492 Non-comparable expression of type object cannot be used in comparison

Tags: sql-server, teiid

I am using `setObject` in `Preparedstatement` for the query `SELECT * FROM table_name where column_name = ?`. The column is of type `DateTimeOffset` of SQL Server and the object is `OffsetDateTime`. But it is giving me the following error:

> TEIID30492 Non-comparable expression of type object cannot be used in comparison

I have tried using the same query without Teiid translator, and it is working.

Any ideas about this kind of error?

Comment: Is `OffsetDateTime` listed on the [Supported types](http://teiid.github.io/teiid-documents/master/content/reference/r_supported-types.html) documentation page?

Comment: No, OffsetDateTime is the api for parsing datetimeoffset, object is the actual datatype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OffsetDateTime roughly maps to a timestamp with timezone, which is currently not supported.  An update was made in Teiid 15 (https://issues.redhat.com/browse/TEIID-5949) to map OffsetDateTime instead to string, which is comparable - but if the comparison is performed in teiid that would be lexically unless you use something like parseTimestamp to handle the conversion.